# java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.spring.webapp.lojavirtual.acesso.persistence.model.Usuario

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, dao

In my spring project, I have implemented a generic class to serve as base for all my Dao class. By example, my class UsuarioHome have this code:

```
@Repository
public class UsuarioHome extends Dao<Usuario> {

    public UsuarioHome() {
        super(Usuario.class);
    }

}
```

and my generic class has this code:

```
public class Dao<E> {

    private final E entity;

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getCurrentSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public Dao(E entity) {  
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Dao(Class<?> classe) {
        this.entity = (E) classe;
    }

    public E getEntity() {
        return this.entity;
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean persist(E transientInstance) {
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
            return true;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean remove(E transientInstance) {
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(transientInstance);
            return true;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean merge(E detachedInstance) {
        try {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(detachedInstance);
            return true;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public E findById(int id) {
        try {
            E instance = (E) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(entity.getClass(), id);
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public E findByField(String field, String value) {
        try {
            String expressao = entity.toString();
            String nome_classe = new String();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expressao);
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                nome_classe = st.nextToken();
            }
            String query = "from "+nome_classe+" where "+field+" = :data";

            Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);
            q.setParameter("data", value);
            E instance = (E) q.uniqueResult();
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional
    public List<E> findAll() {
        try {
            List<E> instance = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entity.getClass()).list();
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

But, when I need retrieve a list of all items from the table, I am receiving 0 items. The method for do this is placed in my class UsuarioService:

```
@Transactional
public List<Usuario> listagem_usuarios() {
    return usuario.findAll();
}
```

where I autowires my Dao class:

```
@Autowired
private UsuarioHome usuario;

@Autowired
private GrupoPermissaoHome grupo_permissao;
```

Anyone can tell what I am doing wrong here? I tested this solution in other projects (simpler than that), and it work.

**UPDATE**

When I try run the application, I am facing a cast error, like this, by example, when this json page is opened:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
<json:object>
<c:forEach var="item" items="${lista}">
      <json:object name="usuario">
         <json:property name="id" value="${item.id}"/>
         <json:property name="login" value="${item.login}"/>
         <json:property name="pnome" value="${item.first_name}"/>
         <json:property name="unome" value="${item.last_name}"/>
         <json:property name="email" value="${item.email}"/>
      </json:object>
</c:forEach>
</json:object>
```

the console shows this error:

```
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp._jspx_meth_json_005fproperty_005f0(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:168)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.access$1(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:156)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp$Helper.invoke1(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:271)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp$Helper.invoke(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:310)
    at atg.taglib.json.JsonObjectTag.doTag(JsonObjectTag.java:63)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp._jspx_meth_json_005fobject_005f1(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:151)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:117)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.access$0(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:98)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp$Helper.invoke0(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:261)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp$Helper.invoke(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:307)
    at atg.taglib.json.JsonObjectTag.doTag(JsonObjectTag.java:63)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp._jspx_meth_json_005fobject_005f0(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:93)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp._jspService(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:68)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Mai 20, 2014 7:40:22 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [json_dispatcher] in context with path [/loja] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/view/json/listagem_usuarios.jsp at line 5

2: <%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
3: <json:object>
4: <c:forEach var="item" items="${lista}">
5:    <json:object name="usuario">
6:       <json:property name="id" value="${item.id}"/>
7:       <json:property name="login" value="${item.login}"/>
8:       <json:property name="pnome" value="${item.first_name}"/>


Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "id"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:166)
    at javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:46)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:1026)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp._jspx_meth_json_005fproperty_005f0(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:168)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.access$1(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:156)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp$Helper.invoke1(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:271)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp$Helper.invoke(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:310)
    at atg.taglib.json.JsonObjectTag.doTag(JsonObjectTag.java:63)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp._jspx_meth_json_005fobject_005f1(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:151)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:117)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.access$0(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:98)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp$Helper.invoke0(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:261)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp$Helper.invoke(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:307)
    at atg.taglib.json.JsonObjectTag.doTag(JsonObjectTag.java:63)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp._jspx_meth_json_005fobject_005f0(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:93)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.view.json.listagem_005fusuarios_jsp._jspService(listagem_005fusuarios_jsp.java:68)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:412)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:263)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:992)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:939)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**UPDATE 2**

After more tests, I verify that when I use:

```
List<E> instance = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entity.getClass()).list();
```

I get an empty list. But when I use:

```
List<E> instance = (List<E>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("select * from usuario").list();
```

I get the data from database, but I can access them, due to an cast error (explained above in the first update)

ps.: the other methods, findById and findByField, are working fine.

Comment: Remove your try/catch blocks, you might find that your methods are throwing an exception to tell you what is going wrong. Performing exception handling in a DAO is nonsensical, you want to do all exception handling at a service level. If the DAO throws an exception its usually for a very good reason.

Comment: to add more to this. None of your catch blocks are logging the error or at least printing the error out to the console for testing purposes.

Comment: I just try run the application without the try/catch blocks from Dao class, but no exception is throw (I guess this can be told before, since the my "handling" for exception was only print the error. What is happening now is, when I try access any member from returned list (usuario.findAll), I get a cast error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solve this issue following the sugestion from this topic:

[Class derived from generic class don't get the correct type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759068/class-derived-from-generic-class-dont-get-the-correct-type)

the final code for the Dao template it's that:

```
public class Dao<E> {

    private final Class<E> entity;

    @Autowired
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    protected Session getCurrentSession(){
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    /*public Dao(E entity) {  
        this.entity = entity;
    }*/

    public Dao(Class<E> classe) {
        this.entity = classe;
    }

    /*public E getEntity() {
        return this.entity;
    }*/

    @Transactional
    public boolean persist(E transientInstance) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().persist(transientInstance);
        return true;
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean remove(E transientInstance) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(transientInstance);
        return true;
    }

    @Transactional
    public boolean merge(E detachedInstance) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(detachedInstance);
        return true;
    }

    @Transactional
    public E findById(int id) {
        E instance = (E) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(entity.getClass(), id);
        return instance;
    }

    @Transactional
    public E findByField(String field, String value) {
        String expressao = entity.toString();
        String nome_classe = new String();
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(expressao);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            nome_classe = st.nextToken();
        }
        String query = "from "+nome_classe+" where "+field+" = :data";

        Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(query);
        q.setParameter("data", value);
        E instance = (E) q.uniqueResult();
        return instance;
    }

    @Transactional
    public List<E> findAll() {
        return (List<E>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entity).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
    }

}
```