# Hibernate query don't retrieving data from database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my spring project, I have this method in my Dao class to return a List of all rows from a table:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Transactional
public List<E> findAll() {
    try {
        List<E> instance = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entity.getClass()).list();
        System.out.println("returned instance with "+instance.size()+" items");
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        System.out.println("returned null");
        return null;
    }
}
```

this method is called from this method from my service class:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'listagem_'+#this.this.name)")
@Transactional
public List<E> listagem() {
    return dao.findAll();
}
```

and this last one it's called from this method from my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="listagem/{pagina}/{items}/{ordem}")
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'listagem_'+#this.this.name)")
public ModelAndView listagem(@PathVariable("pagina") String pagina, @PathVariable("items") String items, @PathVariable("ordem") String ordem) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName("privado/"+this.getName()+"/listagem");

    mav.addObject("lista", serv.listagem());
    mav.addObject("pagina", pagina);
    mav.addObject("items", items);
    mav.addObject("ordem", ordem);

    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(value="listagem.json", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#user, 'listagem_'+#this.this.name)")
public ModelAndView listagem_json(@RequestParam("pagina") String pagina, @RequestParam("items") String items, @RequestParam("ordem") String ordem) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    mav.setViewName(this.getName()+"/listagem");

    mav.addObject("lista", serv.listagem());
    mav.addObject("pagina", pagina);
    mav.addObject("items", items);
    mav.addObject("ordem", ordem);

    return mav;
}
```

the problem it's the method findAll from Dao class it's returning zero elements, despite the fact I make sure the table in database is populated with at least one row.

Anyone can see what's wrong here? I used the same code in other projects, and worked with no problems. This current project it's the first I am using this generic Dao class with the generic controller and service classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How try with `setResultTransformer()`;

```
List<E> instance = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(entity.getClass())
                    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
```

Comment: I try that but still got the same problem (no rows retrieved).

Comment: Please can you show the whole generic dao code as doubt on `entity.getClass()`.

Comment: Yes, this is the complete code for the generic class: https://github.com/klebermo/blog.cms/blob/master/src/main/java/com/config/generic/persistence/Dao.java

Comment: @KleberMota Suspect on `Dao(Class<?> classe)`. Look into this [**thread**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759068/class-derived-from-generic-class-dont-get-the-correct-type/23759461#23759461) answer for Generic DAO class. If still problem, may need to check Service & underlying DAO creation.